# struts dynamic error message handling

Tags: java, struts

I want to display a dynamic error message ,i am having the code as

```
ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("error.plan.foundForUser"));
saveErrors(request, errors);
error.plan.foundForUser={1} Not Found
```

I want to replace 1 with a dynamic value,how to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

In Struts 1.x, if you are trying to display an dynamic ActionMessage (type can be a String,Integer etc.) using Struts ActionMessages class please have a look at the below snippet:

```
ActionMessages msg = new ActionMessages();
msg.add(ACtionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(
                "msg.displaymsg", new Object[] {"Message to be displayed"}));
```

In Property file we must set the property value like this:

```
msg.displaymsg={0}
```

Above defines that argument of zero holds the first value of Object ActionMessage.

```
Above worked for me.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable to ActionMEssage like this,

```
       errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(
                "error.plan.foundForUser", new Object[] {"username"}));
```

Comment: i have an list of users to be appended to the error message
error.plan.foundForUser={1} Not Found
like a,b,,c not found 
how to handle this and      errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(
                "error.plan.foundForUser", new Object[] {"username"}));
is not valid ,i am getting an error to remove second attribute